# Get test number If the line above contains specific text

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, xmllint

I have a junit file. How to get number from testIT?

If the line above contains the text "/system-err" or "/failure" then the test fails and writes to the file fail id test.

If the line above contains the text "/system-out" then the test is successful and writes to the passed file id test.

example "/system-err"

```
<system-err>Assertion Failure at Navigation.swift:88:Failed to get matching snapshot: No matches found for first query match sequence: `Descendants matching type NavigationBar`, given input App element pid: 21141 (no attribute values faulted in)</system-err>
    <system-out>testIT: C477997</system-out>
```

example "/failure"

```
>      <failure message='Assertion Failure at Element.swift:277:Failed to get matching snapshot: No matches found for Elements matching
> predicate &apos;&quot;One&quot; IN identifiers&apos; from input {(
>         Button, identifier: &apos;dictation&apos;, label: &apos;Диктовать&apos;, Disabled,
>         Button, label: &apos;Почему мне не приходит СМС?&apos;,
>         Button, label: &apos;Назад&apos;,
>         Button,
>         Button, label: &apos;Продолжить&apos;
>     )}'>
>         </failure>
>         <system-out>testIT: C478067</system-out>
```

passed test

```
<system-out>      Setting up automation session</system-out>
    <system-out>testIT: C478057</system-out>
```

fail file contains id

```
477997
478067
```

passed file contains id

```
478057
```

I tried

```
xmllint  $1 | awk -F'testIT: C|, | \\(' '/testIT:/{print $2"\n"$4"\n"$6}'| awk 'NF!=0' | sort| uniq|  2>/dev/null > successfullCases.xml
```

but I get

```
470836</system-out>
477975</system-out>
477997</system-out>
478057</system-out>
478067</system-out>
478098</system-out>
```

Full file https://disk.yandex.ru/d/DhdlvwfYj4J00A

Comment: https://xmllint.com/? :-)

Comment: what do you mean? ))

Comment: `sed`, `awk` and `grep` can easily be used in flat textfiles. I have the impression you're dealing with an XML file, so I advise you to use XML-handling tools, like the one in the mentioned URL.

Comment: What have you tried so far that did not work?

Comment: `xmllint  $1 | awk -F'testIT: C|, | \\(' '/testIT:/{print $2"\n"$4"\n"$6}'| awk 'NF!=0' | sort| uniq|  2>/dev/null > successfullCases.xml`
while it turns out only to collect id (there may be several in a line, but not more than three)

Comment: This would be an easy task using a tool/library that handles XML, but you make it difficult to give an answer because you only have a few lines from an XML file. If you can add a simplified/well-formed example of your "junit file" (is that the standard JUnit XML format??), we can offer better suggestions.

Comment: i posted my file https://disk.yandex.ru/d/DhdlvwfYj4J00A

Comment: Not clicking that link, but glad to see you got an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this:

```bash
arr=(`grep -En "C[0-9]{6}" $1 | cut -d":" -f 1 | xargs`)


>fail.out
>err.out
>pass.out

for i in ${!arr[@]}; do
    line_num="${arr[$i]}"
    if head -$line_num $1 | tail -2 | grep -q "/system-err"
    then
        echo -ne "$i) Line: $line_num\t\tError\t\tID: "
        head -$line_num $1 | tail -1 | grep -Eo '[0-9]{6}'
        head -$line_num $1 | tail -1 | grep -Eo '[0-9]{6}' >> err.out
        #--------------------------------------------------------
    elif head -$line_num $1 | tail -2 | grep -q "/failure"
    then
        echo -ne "$i) Line: $line_num\t\tFailure\t\tID: "
        head -$line_num $1 | tail -1 | grep -Eo '[0-9]{6}'
        head -$line_num $1 | tail -1 | grep -Eo '[0-9]{6}' >> fail.out
        # ----------------------------------------------------------
    elif head -$line_num $1 | tail -2 | grep -q "/system-out"
    then
        echo -ne "$i) Line: $line_num\t\tPass\t\tID: "
        head -$line_num $1 | tail -1 | grep -Eo '[0-9]{6}'
        head -$line_num $1 | tail -1 | grep -Eo '[0-9]{6}' >> pass.out
        # ----------------------------------------------------------
    fi
done
```

Save the script in a file and try to run it in this way:

```bash
[user@host]# bash script.sh report.junit
```

Comment: Its work)) Thank you so much )) I tried delete repeated ID add after grep -Eo '[0-9]{6}' | uniq, but this not work )) why?)

Comment: For deleting the repeated IDs you should do your **text processing on output** file. Let the script runs completely and then use `uniq` on it. Based on what you want (I don't know what exactly it is), maybe you need `sort -n` too.

Answer (score 0):

###### Try this:

```bash
grep -Eo '[0-9]{6}' file.txt
```

###### Description:

`-E` or `--extended-regexp`: Interpret PATTERNS as extended regular  expressions

&

`-o` or  `--only-matching`:  Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line,with each such part on a separate output line.

###### More to read:

1. [grep(1): print lines matching pattern - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)

###### Note:

Also, if you want to export the "error", "pass" or "fail", you should write a script which process line by line of your input file.
I can help you more.

Comment: in this case, the file will get a general list of all numbers, without reference to the status of the passage ))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is similar to:

```
$ cat input_file
<system-err>Assertion Failure at Navigation.swift:88:Failed to get matching snapshot: No matches found for first query match sequence: `Descendants matching type NavigationBar`, given input App element pid: 21141 (no attribute values faulted in)</system-err>
    <system-out>testIT: C477997</system-out>
>      <failure message='Assertion Failure at Element.swift:277:Failed to get matching snapshot: No matches found for Elements matching
> predicate &apos;&quot;One&quot; IN identifiers&apos; from input {(
>         Button, identifier: &apos;dictation&apos;, label: &apos;Диктовать&apos;, Disabled,
>         Button, label: &apos;Почему мне не приходит СМС?&apos;,
>         Button, label: &apos;Назад&apos;,
>         Button,
>         Button, label: &apos;Продолжить&apos;
>     )}'>
>         </failure>
>         <system-out>testIT: C478067</system-out>
<system-out>      Setting up automation session</system-out>
    <system-out>testIT: C478057</system-out>
```

Using `sed`

```
$ cat script.sed
N
s~.*/(system-err|failure).*\n.*testIT[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*~\2~pwfail.txt
s~.*/system-out.*\n.*testIT[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*~\1~pwpass.txt
p
```

You can use the script with:

```
$ sed -Enf script.sed input_file
```

Or as a one liner

```
$ sed -Ene 'N;{s~.*/(system-err|failure).*\n.*testIT[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*~\2~pwfail.txt' -e 's~.*/system-out.*\n.*testIT[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*~\1~pwpass.txt' -e '}' input_file
```

**Output**

```
$ head {pass,fail}.txt
==> pass.txt <==
478057

==> fail.txt <==
477997
478067
```

Comment: in general, everything seems to be ok. But I noticed that not all numbers were recorded from the file. For example, successful ones are: `477975 478057 478098`
unsuccessful: `477997 470836 478067`. And we have 2 successful and 1 unsuccessful in the file.
file link https://disk.yandex.ru/d/DhdlvwfYj4J00A